# Display automatically input panel, and keep the entry focused on tizen

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-native-app

What i'm trying to achieve is that when a popup is displayed, the input panel (keyboard) appears as well, and when the user start typing it also update the entry content that is on the panel content.

Unfortunately this appear to be quite complex in Tizen.

What I obtained so far is that the popup is displayed, the kepad too, but when I press buttons on the keypad they are not updating the entry.

In order to start real typing even if the keypad is displayed, i have to tap on the entry.

I did many different tries, without success. The following is the first version of the code and i try to list all the changes i tested:

```
Evas_Object *popup, *layout;
popup = elm_popup_add(parent);
elm_popup_align_set(popup, ELM_NOTIFY_ALIGN_FILL, 1.0);
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(popup, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
elm_object_part_text_set(popup, "title,text", "Use energy");

layout = elm_layout_add(popup);
elm_layout_theme_set(layout, "layout", "drawer", "panel");
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(layout, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
elm_object_content_set(popup, layout);

Evas_Object *entry = elm_entry_add(layout);
set_number_on_entry(entry, 0);
elm_entry_input_panel_layout_set(entry, ELM_INPUT_PANEL_LAYOUT_NUMBERONLY);
elm_entry_input_panel_show(entry);
elm_object_part_content_set(layout, "elm.swallow.content" , entry);
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, APP_TAG, elm_entry_entry_get(entry));
container->entry = entry;
Evas_Object *button1;
button1 = elm_button_add(popup);
elm_object_text_set(button1, "OK");
elm_object_part_content_set(popup, "button1", button1);
elm_object_style_set(button1, "popup");
evas_object_smart_callback_add(button1, "clicked", ok_pressed_energy, container);

/* Add a "Cancel" button to popup */
button1 = elm_button_add(popup);
elm_object_text_set(button1, "Cancel");
elm_object_part_content_set(popup, "button2", button1);

evas_object_smart_callback_add(button1, "clicked", dismissed_cb, popup);
evas_object_smart_callback_add(popup, "dismissed", dismissed_cb, NULL);
container->popup = popup;
evas_object_show(popup);
elm_object_focus_set(entry, EINA_TRUE);
elm_entry_cursor_end_set(entry);
```

The first version of the code (the one above) was trying to display the panel while the popup was still creating. So maybe the show call could have impacted on the focus status for the entry.

The following are the changes i tried in order:

1. I tried to explicitly allow the focus on the entry using:

`elm_object_focus_allow_set(entry, EINA_TRUE);`

without luck. I also tried to explicitly give the focus to the entry just after the focus allow was set to true, again no success.

2. I tried to show the panel after the entry was focused (then after the show function for popup was called. Again not working.
3. Added:

   `elm_entry_input_panel_enabled_set(entry, EINA_TRUE);`

The documentation for that function says:
*If true, the input panel is appeared when entry is clicked or has a focus*.
Not working

4. Tried to display the code using the context obtained from the entry with the following code:

   ```
   Ecore_IMF_Context *imf_context = (Ecore_IMF_Context*)         
   elm_entry_imf_context_get(entry);
   if(imf_context){
       dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, APP_TAG , "Imf context");
       ecore_imf_context_input_panel_show(imf_context);
   }
   ```

I tried to post the question also on the Tizen foru, but i still didn't get an answer that solve my problem, this is the link: https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/entry-on-popup-focus#comment-27748

What i'm doing wrong? I tried everything but at the moment with no luck. And unfortunately the documentation is not covering this use case (that i think is quite common).

Any help?